# Notification led on amoled screen emulation coding

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to recreate notification led on my amoled phone screen and I was wondering if there is any android api to show something when screen is locked.
I know there are already several apps like NotifyBuddy but I would like to do it myself.

I'm a c# developer,but also other languages accepted.

Comment: You can schedule a local notification as mention [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications#create-the-androidnotificationmanager-class).

Comment: I need to reproduce the LED on the amoled.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get the point, can you make your question a little clear? Share us some codes or examples.